# PSEXEC and file uploading

Tags: psexec

Does anyone knows a command how to upload file to remote computer using psexec?

In my case, I need to upload powershell script with psexec to remote computer un than run it on remote computer.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for PSEexec says:

```
psexec [\\computer[,computer2[,...] | @file]][-u user [-p psswd][-n s][-r servicename][-h][-l][-s|-e][-x][-i [session]][-c [-f|-v]][-w directory][-d][-<priority>][-a n,n,...] cmd [arguments]
```

You should be be able to copy it using e.g.

```
psexec.exe \\192.168.0.201 -u 192.168.0.201\Administrator -p password -c -csrc "C:\path to\myscript.ps1" myscript.ps1
```

**Note:** A range of things could go wrong, and you'd need the right privileges etc in order for this to work as you intend. PSExec is a bit old-school If you simply want to copy the file, you can use regular copy (with net-use). If you want to access the remote computer and copy/execute a powershell script, I'd recommend taking a look at PSRemoting.

PSRemoting would be ideal for what you're trying to achieve (that is if you have a newer windows version with newer Powershell).

The documentation on remoting can be found on http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347744.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply! But for default, PSRemoting is disabled, right? So how can i enable for each PC it to run script remote?

Comment: There's a powershell script to enable remoting through WMI on different computers: http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Enable-PSRemoting-Remotely-6cedfcb0 . If you have access to each and every machine (e.g. through remote desktop or other), you can follow the documentation from http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849694.aspx